# If $b \in \mathbb F$, then $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb F^4: x_3 = 5x_4 + b\}$ is subspace of $\mathbb F^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $b \in \mathbb F$, then $U = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb F^4: x_3 = 5x_4 + b\}$ is subspace of $ \mathbb F^4 \iff b = 0$.

I know the thread "[show that {$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{F}^4$:$x_3=5x_4+b$} is a subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473018/show-that-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-in-mathbbf4x-3-5x-4b-is-a-subspace)" already exists. I tried slightly different approach and only in one direction, but unsure if that qualifies as a proof of the direction:

Suppose $u = (x_1, x_2, 5x_4, x_4)$ and $v = (y_1, y_2, 5y_4, y_4) \in U$. Let $a \in \mathbb F$.
Then $a(u + v)  = (a(x_1 + y_1) + a(x_2 + y_2) + 5a(x_4 + y_4) + a(x_4 + y_4))$. So, $a(u + v) \in U$
Since $a \in U$, scalar $0 \in U$. Then $0(u + v) = 0$, so then the vector $0 \in U$.

Des this method work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe write it a little more clearly:
Suppose $u=(x_1,x_2,5x_4+b,x_4), v=(y_1,y_2,5y_4+b,y_4) \in U$ and let $a \in \mathbb{F}$. Setting $b=0$ and $z_n:=(x_n+y_n)$, we obtain
$$a(u+v)=a((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)+(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4))\\  \hspace{3.3cm}=a((x_1+y_1),(x_2+y_2),(x_3+y_3),(x_4+y_4)) \\ \hspace{-1.3cm} =(az_1,az_2,az_3,az_4) \\ \hspace{0.1cm} = (az_1,az_2,a(x_3+y_3),az_4) \\ \hspace{0.35cm} =(az_1,az_2,5a(x_4+y_4),az_4) \\= (az_1,az_2,5az_4,az_4) \in U$$

I would also reword the last part: Since $0 \in \mathbb{F}$ (every field must have an additive identity element) and $a(u+v) \in U$, we have $0(u+v)=0 \in U$.
We could also show it the following way:

Suppose $b = 0$. Then we can write $$U = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{F}^4:x_3=5x_4 \}.$$ Since $(0,0,0,0)=(0,0,5 \cdot 0,0),$ we have $(0,0,0,0)= 0 \in U.$